# how can i convert a wpf application to exe

Tags: wpf

How can I convert a wpf application to a .exe which will run on all Microsoft Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 10):

If you're in visual studio, hit F7.

The application will be compiled into an exe file that can then be executed.  It will usually be located underneath your solution directory:

```
SolutionDir\Bin\(Debug|Release)\Solution.exe
```

This file will only be able to run on Windows computers that have the necessary version of the CLR installed.  As far as I know there's no way around that requirement.

Comment: Used ctrl+B to build, and It builds and generates a .exe, but it also seems to have other files in the bin directory like dll file and some jsons. When I test the exe in another computer it won't run, like it needs the other files. Am I missing something to package it in one file?

Answer (score 5):

:) Compile in VS2008 and remember to check out the Bin{Debug|Release} folder of the project location to see the exe

Answer (score 1):

Build it in Visual Studio.  It should run on any Windows system that has the correct framework installed. (Potentially .NET 3.5sp1, depending on what you included.)

Answer (score 1):

WPF is by default an .exe, but will need .NET 3+. You can't create a WPF .exe and expect it to work on all Windows version, regardless whether the platform you've compiled your application for is installed.

It's like a library dependency in C/C++. Certain libraries don't work on older versions of Windows.